# Office 365 Post-Service Upgrade, only part of the site has enterprise tab (records center) Why?

Tags: records-center

We have a site collection that has records center subsites. However, somewhere further down the subsite chain we no longer have to ability to access the templates from the Enterprise Tab, as if those subsites are pre-service upgrade.

Is there something else going on preventing us from seeing the Enterprise Tab when creating a new sub-site?

Thanks